# dynamic system using Hamiltonian

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control

I'm trying to solve an equation from the next form:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
 x_1'(t)&=&x_2(t) \\ 
\\x_2'(t)&=&-0.25x_1(t)-u(t)x_2(t) 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

I'm not sure how to solve this because there is a multiple between the controller $u(t)$ and the state space $x_2(t)$.

My question is how can i proceed with solving this using Hamiltonian in this case.

Thank you.

Comment: You need some information about $u(t)$

Comment: the information i have is: 0<=u(t)<=1. Thanks you.

Comment: You haven't stated what your optimization criteria and boundary conditions  are. Is it a minimum time problem?

Comment: Find the minimum control which steers the system to the origin in minimum time. Thank you

Comment: Is $a$ positive or negative? This also affects the optimal trajectories.

Comment: I updated the question, a=0.25

Comment: You could go straight, write the Hamiltonian $H=-1+\psi_1x_2-\psi_2(0.25x_1+ux_2)$, find the optimal control to be $u^*=0$ if $\psi_2x_2\ge 0$ and $u^*=1$ otherwise etc., but this will probably not bring you any further. Instead of this I'd suggest you to see the literature on time-optimal control of bilinear systems. Your system falls into this class and so, you may find some information specifically related to your problem.